# There is no strsafe.h in MinGW? What to use instead?

Tags: c++, mingw, strsafe

Compiling first snippet from here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499(VS.85).aspx

gives: `d:\!TC\cpp\control.cpp:4:21: fatal error: strsafe.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.`

Comment: So yes, but what to use instead ? Is it as show-stop with this code ?

Comment: It's a Microsoft extension. Don't look in msdn if you don't develop in VS.

Comment: Yes, but maybe there is a replacement, maybe some function here to replace by another... now look after commenting out this one offending include it seems that the `StringCchPrintf()` is missing.

Comment: use sprintf from stdlib, but beware, it is less secure. (or atleast that's what Microsoft is trying to make you believe)

Comment: Mingw is an open source project.  A header like this doesn't become available until *somebody* steps up the plate and writes it.  That somebody could be you.

Comment: @HansPassant: that's *years* of learning to me... maybe in 2015 or 2025... :P

Comment: @Dani, I find some of the examples there really useful once I change the MS extensions. I'm on MinGW too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Download [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuigroup/ccv-multicam/master/branches/test/videoInput_GUID/videoInputSrcAndDemos/libs/DShow/Include/strsafe.h): it's a header file. Copy it to the path "/mingw/include"  folder and it will work thats all

Comment: Looks like they moved their repos to github. Here's the new link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuigroup/ccv-multicam/master/branches/test/videoInput_GUID/videoInputSrcAndDemos/libs/DShow/Include/strsafe.h

Comment: thank you for the hack; but than I am missing _vsnwprintf (which is called in <strsafe.h>, but in microsoft it is defined in <stdio.h> and <stdarg.h>).

Answer (score 2):

You're using C++, per your tags. The "strsafe" functions are an attempt to make C a tiny bit safer. But C++ is already far safer. E.g the `StringCchPrintf` function is not nearly as safe as `std::osstream`.