# C++ Looping Through Files In Directory and Writing to a Different Directory

Tags: c++, io

I am attempting to modify some existing C++ code to work with my needs, but having never used C++ before, I am having some difficulties.

My goal is:

```
--> time and memory-intensive processes for preparation

for each file in directory:
    open file;
    generate a tagged representation; //the current code just does this
    write file; //different directory but same filename
```

The reason I do not want to just call the C++ program for each file (with, for instance, a shell script) is that prior to the below code running, time and memory-intensive pre-processing steps are performed. (These take about 45-60sec. while the code only takes about 2-5sec. to run.)

I have pasted the section of the code below. I want to read the arguments from the command line.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  /*
  pre-processing stuff
  */

  /* for each file */
  HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
  string path = argv[1];
  string outpath = argv[2];
  WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;

  //EDIT 2:
  cout << "Path: " << path << '\n'; 
  cout << "Outpath: " << outpath << '\n';

  hFind = FindFirstFile(path.c_str(), &ffd);
  if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    cout << "error searching directory\n";
    return false;
  }

  do {
    //istream *is(&std::cin);
    string filePath = path + ffd.cFileName;
    ifstream in( filePath.c_str() );
    if (in) {
      /* for each line */
      string line;
      int n = 1;
      string str;
      string fullOutpath = outpath + ffd.cFileName;
      ofstream File;
      File.open(fullOutpath);
      while (getline(in, line)) {
        if (line.size() > 1024) {
          cerr << "warning: the sentence seems to be too long at line " << n;
          cerr << " (please note that the input should be one-sentence-per-line)." << endl;
        }

        string postagged = bidir_postag(line, vme, vme_chunking, dont_tokenize);

        /* output to file */
        File << postagged << endl;
        //cout << postagged << endl;

        /* increment counter */
        n++;
      }
      File.close();
    } else {
      cout << "Problem opening file " << ffd.cFileName << "\n";
    }
  } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);

  if (GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) {
    cout << "Something went wrong during searching\n"; 
  }
  return true;
}
```

Currently, I am getting a compiler error: **EDIT**: compiler error fixed, thanks Blood!, but see below...

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::open<std::string&>
```

Any thoughts? Please let me know if you need more code/information. Also, I should add that I'm running these on Windows XP using command prompt.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

It now compiles (thanks Blood), though when it runs it is only attempting to open the directory, not the files in the directory.

```
Problem opening file directory_name.
```

The ifstream should be opening the files in teh directory, not the directory itself.

**EDIT 2:**

I am running the executable fromt he command line with the following prompt:

```
.\tag.exe C:\indir C:\outdir
```

I have also tried:

```
.\tag.exe C:\indir\* C:\outdir\
```

This enumerates all the files, but how can I capture them? Also, is there a simpler way to modify my code/input?

I have also tried:

```
.\tag.exe C:\indir\ C:\outdir\
```

This gives: error searching directory.

**EDIT 3:**

Using:

```
.\tag.exe "C:\indir\*" C:\outdir\
```

I get the output:

```
Problem opening file .

Problem opening file ..

Problem opening file 2967

Problem opening file 2966

Problem opening file 4707

etc. (100s)
```

**Solution:**

Here are the key changes to the code (thanks Nate Kohl!):

```
string path = argv[1];
path += "\\*";

hFind = FindFirstFile(path.c_str(),&ffd);

    // in the 'do-while' loop
    string filePath = argv[1];
    filePath += "\\";
    filePath += ffd.cFileName;

    ifstream in(filePath.c_str());

    //regarding the outpath
    fullOutpath = outpath + "\\";
    fullOutpath += ffd.cFileName;
    File.open(fullOutpath.c_str());
```

and from the command line:

```
.\tag.exe C:\indir C:\outdir
```

The help was very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you're passing the right `path` format to `FindFirstFile`.

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> To examine a directory that is not a root directory, use the path to
>   that directory, without a trailing backslash. For example, an argument
>   of "C:\Windows" returns information about the directory "C:\Windows",
>   not about a directory or file in "C:\Windows". **To examine the files
>   and directories in "C:\Windows", use an lpFileName of "C:\Windows\***".

---

**Edit:**

I'm not near a windows box right now (so this may not compile!) but I imagine that "loop over each file in a directory" would look something like this:

```
// argv[1] is the input path with no trailing characters, e.g. "c:\indir"

// add a wildcard because FindFirstFile expects e.g. "c:\indir\*"
TCHAR wildcard_path[MAX_PATH];
PathCombine(wildcard_path, argv[1], "*"); 

// iterate over each file
WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(wildcard_path, &ffd);
if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) { } // error

do {
   // ignore directories
   if (!(ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) {

      // create a full path for each file we find, e.g. "c:\indir\foo.txt"
      TCHAR file_path[MAX_PATH];
      PathCombine(file_path, argv[1], ffd.cFileName);

      // ...and do something with file_path.
   }
} while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);

FindClose(hFind);
```

Comment: I'm running the compiled executable from the command line and specified the files as C:\indir\* C:\outdir\ (I think this is what you suggested?). In this case, 'path' become the first file in the directory and outpath becomes the second file in the indirectory. Also, I get the error "Problem opening file 0064" above (note: 0064 is one of the correct filenames.

Comment: @DavidC: it should be `C:\indir\*` (note the trailing `\*`).

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Sorry, typo. I tried what you're suggesting. It lists all files in the directory, so that argv[1] == first file, argv[2] == second file, ... , argv[-1] == output-directory. Thus, I end up with Path: C:\indir\0064  and  Outpath: C:\indir\0151, and "problem opening file 0064".

Comment: @DavidC: oh, your shell is performing wildcard expansion prior to your application! You should pass just `C:\indir` from the command line in this case and append `\*` in your application.

Comment: @DavidC: try putting quotes around it, e.g. `foo.exe "C:\indir\*"`

Comment: @Nate: Thanks, that seems to have taken care of that problem. Now, I'm getting "Problem opening file .\nProblem opening file ..\nProblem opening file 2967\nProblem opening file ... ... ... Any thoughts? See Edit 3 in my question for more details.

Comment: Try having your error message display `filePath`, which is the actual path that's failing to open.  I suspect that concatenating the path and the filename isn't correct, especially now that the path contains a `*` character.

Comment: @NateKohl: You're correct. Thanks! The file path includes "C:\indir\\*0458". Any quick thoughts on how to remove that? (how to get a substring of the filepath?)

Comment: @DavidC: Maybe a better approach is to do like @sixlettervariables suggested: 1. pass in the path as `C:\indir`, 2. use `PathCombine` on the path and a `*` and list the files, 3. use `PathCombine` again on the path and each filename to get a full path to each file.  There's a similar approach shown at  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2043959/98654

Comment: @NateKohl: Thanks, I implemented what you have above (except with PathCombine(wildcard_path, argv[1], **_T("*")**);  ) and am getting "undefined reference to '_imp_PathCombineA@12'  
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status". Any thoughts?

Comment: @DavidC: an alternative is to manually copy (`StringCchCopy`) and contatenate (`StringCchCat`), like they do in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @DavidC: or to use `PathCombine`, include `Shlwapi.lib` in your project settings as a dependency.

Comment: @NateKohl: I am having [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970617/there-is-no-strsafe-h-in-mingw-what-to-use-instead) problem with StringCchCopy, etc., and none of the suggestions were particularly helpful (sprinf doesn't compile and printf leaves `Xo"Xo"error searching directory` where the 'o' is raised. I had included the appropriate header file for PathCombine (still getting the "undefined reference" bit above). Thanks for all your help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13381/discussion-between-nate-kohl-and-david-c)