# Mingw doesn't find file strsafe.h while compiling OpenVC library

Tags: opencv, mingw, strsafe

I want start playing with the OpenCV library, but I have a problem during the build process. I am on Windows 10 with the Mingw compiler. When I launch the command **mingw32-make** after a while, I get the following errors:

`C:\Github\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_dshow.cpp:337:21: fatal error: strsafe.h: No such file or directory
 #include <strsafe.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
modules\videoio\CMakeFiles\opencv_videoio.dir\build.make:187: recipe for target 'modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_dshow.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_dshow.cpp.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:4340: recipe for target 'modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:159: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2`

[image]

The incriminated file is **cap_dshow.cpp**, and the compiler says that is missing the header file *strsafe.h*. Inside the folder C:\MinGW\include this file is not present and I don't know where to find this.

I've installed MinGW compiler (and other things) with a tool called "MinGW Installation Manager". With this tool I can install also other libraries, but I don't know if one of these contains the file *strsafe.h*.

[image]

My question is likely a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970617/there-is-no-strsafe-h-in-mingw-what-to-use-instead), but the accepted answer has a broken link.

Answer (score 0):

I have Microsoft SDK installed and found the strsafe.h file in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin".

Adding "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin" to the **Path** system environment variable worked.