# Error in iterative directory listing using C++

Tags: c++, directory-listing

I've come across this code for directory listing on Windows using C++,and I've understood that you can search a directory with these APIs: FindFirstFileEx, FindNextFile and CloseFind. You'll need to #include , that'll get you access to the Windows API.

I'm not able to understand how this code works, as a result not able to make out the compilation error.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strcat.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "User32.lib")

void DisplayErrorBox(LPTSTR lpszFunction);

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
 WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
 LARGE_INTEGER filesize;
 TCHAR szDir[MAX_PATH];
 size_t length_of_arg;
 HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
 DWORD dwError=0;

// If the directory is not specified as a command-line argument,
// print usage.

if(argc != 2)
{
   _tprintf(TEXT("\nUsage: %s <directory name>\n"), argv[0]);
   return (-1);
}

// Check that the input path plus 3 is not longer than MAX_PATH.
// Three characters are for the "\*" plus NULL appended below.

StringCchLength(argv[1], MAX_PATH, &length_of_arg);

if (length_of_arg > (MAX_PATH - 3))
{
  _tprintf(TEXT("\nDirectory path is too long.\n"));
   return (-1);
}

_tprintf(TEXT("\nTarget directory is %s\n\n"), argv[1]);

// Prepare string for use with FindFile functions.  First, copy the
// string to a buffer, then append '\*' to the directory name.

StringCchCopy(szDir, MAX_PATH, argv[1]);
StringCchCat(szDir, MAX_PATH, TEXT("\\*"));

// Find the first file in the directory.

hFind = FindFirstFile(szDir, &ffd);

if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFind)
{
   DisplayErrorBox(TEXT("FindFirstFile"));
   return dwError;
}

// List all the files in the directory with some info about them.

do
{
   if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
   {
      _tprintf(TEXT("  %s   <DIR>\n"), ffd.cFileName);
   }
   else
   {
      filesize.LowPart = ffd.nFileSizeLow;
      filesize.HighPart = ffd.nFileSizeHigh;
      _tprintf(TEXT("  %s   %ld bytes\n"), ffd.cFileName, filesize.QuadPart);
  }
}
while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);

dwError = GetLastError();
if (dwError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
{
   DisplayErrorBox(TEXT("FindFirstFile"));
}

FindClose(hFind);
return dwError;
```

}

```
void DisplayErrorBox(LPTSTR lpszFunction)
{
    // Retrieve the system error message for the last-error code

 LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
 LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
 DWORD dw = GetLastError();

 FormatMessage(
     FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
     FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
     FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
     NULL,
     dw,
     MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
     (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
     0, NULL );

 // Display the error message and clean up

 lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT,
      (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf)+lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction)+40)*sizeof(TCHAR));
 StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf,
    LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
    TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"),
    lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf);
MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);

LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
}
```

Gives out the followoing error on codeblocks:

```
   fatal error: strcat.h: No such file or directory
   #include <strcat.h>
                ^
```

compilation terminated.

Comment: `#include <strcat.h>` -> `#include <string.h>`

Comment: Theres whole lot of error I get here:

        ( error: 'StringCchLength' was not declared in this scope
    StringCchLength(argv[1], MAX_PATH, &length_of_arg); )
                                                     ^
Again,

        ( error: 'StringCchCopy' was not declared in this scope
    StringCchCopy(szDir, MAX_PATH, argv[1]);)

        Also,

                   ( error: 'StringCchCat' was not declared in this scope
    StringCchCat(szDir, MAX_PATH, TEXT("\\*")); )

Comment: Google "StringCchCat", first hit and read.

Comment: When working with Windows, MSDN is your friend. Scroll down to the end of this page to see what header is required: [MSDN: StringCchLength function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: @JohnnyMopp : Thank you for guiding through, although I did follow this, error crops up fatal error: strsafe.h: No such file or directory
 #include <strsafe.h>

Comment: What compiler are you using? If not VS, see: [There is no strsafe.h in MinGW? What to use instead?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10970617/669576)

Comment: I was using codeblocks previously, but now working with VS and this is the error VS gives:

'11may.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'11may.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0x10d8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[6072] 11may.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Answer (score -1):

`strcat` is defined in `string.h` not `strcat.h`

Then, you do not seem to be using `strcat`, maybe you can remove that.

Comment: The error I get on writing <string.h> is : 
      
    
        error: 'StringCchLength' was not declared in this scope

Comment: That function is defined in `<strsafe.h>`. That header is part of the Windows SDK.

Comment: On using this header
fatal error: strsafe.h: No such file or directory
 #include <strsafe.h>

Comment: Did you install the Windows SDK? Did you include the configure your IDE to use Windows SDK the headers and libraries?